# View receiving 2 models combined fails to pass one of them to a Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

## **PLEASE DISREGARD THIS QUESTION ...it was the result of CODING a DUPLICATED Controller's Action by mistake.**

Currently using VS2012 and MVC5

**MODEL**

```
public class MainModel  
{  
    public Model1 mainData { get; set; }  
    public Model2 partialData { get; set; }  
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MainModel model = new MainModel();
    model.mainData = db.Retrieve_Model1_Data();
    var result = db.Retrieve_Model2_Data();

    Model2 m = new Model2();
    m.field1 = result.field1
    m.field2 = result.field2

    model.partialData = m;

    return View(model);
}

public PartialViewResult _partialView(Model2 model)  
{  
    return PartialView(model);  
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<div>  
    // THIS WORKS  
    @foreach (var item in Model.mainData)
    @Html.Label(item.field);
</div>


<div>  
    // THIS FAILS
    @Html.Partial("_partialView", (Model2)Model.partialData)
</div>
```

===================
I have tried various things here, from passing only the model, or passing the model itself but I always get an exception.

**EXCEPTION**
Using the current code above, I get the following exception

> > The model item passed into the dictionary is of type MainModel, but this dictionary requires a model item of type Model2.

If I remove the typecasting on (Model2)Model.partialData), the exception I get is this

> > CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

**QUESTION**
What's the right way to pass model.partialData to a partial view from the main view ??

Comment: @thepirat000 ..my mistake, somebody decided to duplicate a controller action and I was coding the wrong one. Sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong "model".

Use "model" with a capital "M":

```
@Html.Partial("_partialView", (Model2)Model.partialData)
```

Notice that in the `for-loop` you are using the correct one.

Also, since you are probably using a strong-type view, you won't need to type cast it. So you can remove the `(Model2)`.

Comment: If I don't typecast, I get this exception: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: It was misspelled on the StackO question. The current code does have capital M.

Comment: My mistake ..i was adding code to the wrong controller that somebody decided to duplicate, Sorry !!! It's all working now.